# Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."LeqadoviProjekt-ear-1.1.ear".STRUCTURE:

Tags: java, wildfly, pom.xml

I develop Java EE application with parent pom project and with the few modules. I have 2 EJB modules, 1 web (war) module and 1 EAR module. When i try to deploy ear module to Wildfy 21.0.0, the server was giving to the error:
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.LeqadoviProjekt-ear-1.1.ear".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.LeqadoviProjekt-ear-1.1.ear".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.LeqadoviProjekt-ear-1.1.ear
at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:116)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)

The IDE that i used was Eclipse. The project structure:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHkmj.jpg) .
Is it correct to deploy ear module if i have parent pom project or i must deploy parent project?

```
The context of parent pom was next:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.efd.hsostaric.svi</groupId>
    <artifactId>LeadoviProjekt_svi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <url>http://www.wildfly.org</url>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>LeadoviProjekt_svi</name>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>2.0.1.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-javaee8-with-tools</artifactId>
                <version>17.0.1.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <modules>
        <module>LeadoviProjekt-war</module>
        <module>LeadoviProjekt-ejb</module>
        <module>LeadoviProjekt-ejb-bll</module>
        <module>LeqadoviProjekt-ear</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

I would be ver y gratefull for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Is that the whole error message? I'd expect a "Caused by: ". What you've pasted only says something went wrong when trying to deploy but doesn't provide any reason why. If your IDE doesn't provide any more information I'd look into wildfly's logs, there's bound to be an explicit error there

Answer (score 0):

That's the full error:

```
20:49:18,831 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."LeqadoviProjekt-ear-1.1.ear".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."LeqadoviProjekt-ear-1.1.ear".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "LeqadoviProjekt-ear-1.1.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:189)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0031: Unable to process modules in application.xml for EAR ["/C:/Users/Hrvoje-PC/wildfly-21.0.0.Final/standalone/data/managed-exploded/LeqadoviProjekt-ear-1.1.ear"], module file org.efd.hsostaric-LeadoviProjekt-ejb-1.1.jar not found
    at org.jboss.as.ee.structure.EarStructureProcessor.deploy(EarStructureProcessor.java:187)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
    ... 8 more

20:49:18,842 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "LeqadoviProjekt-ear-1.1.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"LeqadoviProjekt-ear-1.1.ear\".STRUCTURE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"LeqadoviProjekt-ear-1.1.ear\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0031: Unable to process modules in application.xml for EAR [\"/C:/Users/Hrvoje-PC/wildfly-21.0.0.Final/standalone/data/managed-exploded/LeqadoviProjekt-ear-1.1.ear\"], module file org.efd.hsostaric-LeadoviProjekt-ejb-1.1.jar not found"}}
20:49:18,844 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "LeqadoviProjekt-ear-1.1.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"LeqadoviProjekt-ear-1.1.ear\".STRUCTURE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"LeqadoviProjekt-ear-1.1.ear\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0031: Unable to process modules in application.xml for EAR [\"/C:/Users/Hrvoje-PC/wildfly-21.0.0.Final/standalone/data/managed-exploded/LeqadoviProjekt-ear-1.1.ear\"], module file org.efd.hsostaric-LeadoviProjekt-ejb-1.1.jar not found"}}
20:49:18,848 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment LeqadoviProjekt-ear-1.1.ear (runtime-name: LeqadoviProjekt-ear-1.1.ear) in 3ms
```

Was mybe error that i override some dependencies from Wildfly-javaee8.pom.pom or mybe that i added target runtime to each module?

Comment: The relevant part : "Unable to process modules in application.xml for EAR  [...], module file org.efd.hsostaric-LeadoviProjekt-ejb-1.1.jar not found".

Comment: I find the presence of a package name before the jar name suspicious. Maybe a mistake in your application.xml ? If not start by making sure that your EAR does indeed include the LeadoviProjekt-ejb-1.1.jar jar